# Drop into read-eval-print loop from PHP code?

Tags: php

Is there a way to drop into a read-eval-print loop from inside PHP code during execution, in a script that was run from the command line? That is, like php -a or phpsh? Or do I have to re-implement a REPL from scratch? I can't find any way to do it.

To clarify: the reason why I need to do this is that I want to automatically include all the files in my project once the REPL starts, instead of having to manually include everything by hand.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Isn't it easier to start the built-in REPL and execute the script file?

Comment: Clarified--there may be many includes I want to do across a large project, and that may require a lot of typing once the REPL starts. Given that PHP REPLs crash when a fatal error is hit, a lot of error-prone typing is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the file when you enter the php shell...

`php -a`

`<?php require("core.php"); ?>`

core.php:

```
 require_once("somefile.php");
 require_once("anotherfile.php");
 require_once("yetanotherfile.php");
 dosomething();
 // Here, it'll drop back to the shell.
```

If you have a core file that processes a request by calling a function, you can bypass that function call when it is remotely required, using:

```
if (basename($argv[0]) == basename(__FILE__)) { process_request(); }
```

Comment: Is there a way to run a shell script that echos the require("core.php") line into the shell and then gives control back to the user? I tried doing this but it closes after the echo.